# Rails 4.2 ActiveSupport Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Im a getting an error using the command in rails 4.2.0 (not beta version)

```
rails g
```

error:

```
Could not find activesupport-4.2.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

but running bundle install i do have activesupport-4.2.0 installed...

```
Using thread_safe 0.3.4
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.2.0  
.....
```

this command

```
bundle exec show activesupport
```

error

```
bundler: command not found: show
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

this command

```
bundle show activesupport
```

output

```
/home/todd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@blog/gems/activesupport-4.2.0
```

running

```
bundle exec rails g
```

gives me the same error as running 'rails g'

---

ran

```
echo $PATH | grep rvm
```

output

`/home/todd/.rvm/gems/ruby2.1.4@blog/bin:/home/todd/.rvm/gems/ruby2.1.4@global/bin:/home/todd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin:/home/todd/.rvm/bin:/home/todd/bin:/usr/local/bin/exercism:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/home/todd/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

Comment: Did you try `bundle update`?

Comment: Run `bundle exec show activesupport` to see your current version

Comment: i did bundle update of course. bundle exec show activesupport gives me an error. bundle shoe activesupport gives me the correct path. updated question

Comment: Is RVM is in your path? `echo $PATH`

Comment: yes. updating question with output now

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your `rails` executable isn't from bundle, try:

```
bundle exec rails g
```

Comment: that command did not work either. Updated the question to include outputs of the commands i was asked to run

Answer (score 1):

I think it was an rvm path problem or bad install. I just reinstalled the application and made a new rvm gem. Now it works like a charm. Thanks for the help!